# jQuery close when click outside object for working in Firefix and IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

I have basket that appears when someone clicks a button. I'm trying to make it so it closes when there's a click outside the element. I have made a fiddle to illustrate the problem. It works in chrome but doesn't in Firefox and IE - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the link http://jsfiddle.net/H9sFy/6/

```
$(document).click( function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if( ! target.hasClass( '.cart_menu') && target.parents( '.cart_menu:eq(0)').length === 0 )
    {
         $(".cart_menu").toggle();
    }
});

$(".cart_menu").hide();

$('.show_cart').click(function(){
    $(".cart_menu").toggle();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Need to pass event in the click function to make your fiddle work http://jsfiddle.net/H9sFy/7/

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass the event param in the click function

```
$('.show_cart').click(function(event) {
    $(".cart_menu").toggle();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H9sFy/7/